# Discover SQL Server procedure default parameters using SYS or INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, optional-parameters

Like Oracle, SQL Server supports parameter defaults in stored procedures. Oracle syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_default (
  p_in_number   IN  number   := 0,
  p_out_number  OUT number,
  p_in_varchar  IN  varchar2 := '0',
  p_out_varchar OUT varchar2,
  p_in_date     IN  date     := date '1981-07-10',
  p_out_date    OUT date
)
```

SQL Server syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_default (
  @p_in_number       INTEGER = 0,
  @p_out_number      INTEGER OUT,
  @p_in_varchar      VARCHAR(10) = '0',
  @p_out_varchar     VARCHAR(10) OUT,
  @p_in_date         DATE = '1981-07-10',
  @p_out_date        DATE OUT
)
```

With Oracle, I can discover defaults using this query:

```
SELECT argument_name, defaulted FROM all_arguments WHERE object_id = :proc_id
```

How can I discover this in SQL Server selecting from `sys` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables? I don't see any useful column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`, and the `sys.parameters.has_default_value` seems not to be set correctly (!)

Note, I have asked as similar question about DB2:

[Discover DB2 procedure default parameters using SYSCAT tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838076/discover-db2-procedure-default-parameters-using-syscat-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no simple way to do it. As the [documentation for `has_default_value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx) states:

> SQL Server only maintains default values for CLR objects in this catalog view; therefore, this column has a value of 0 for Transact-SQL objects. To view the default value of a parameter in a Transact-SQL object, query the `definition` column of the `sys.sql_modules` catalog view, or use the `OBJECT_DEFINITION` system function.

So you'd have to pull the whole stored proc definition out and parse it yourself to determine the value.

---

Side note: I'd be wary of `@p_in_date DATE = '1981-07-10'`. I know that the `date` datatype is a bit more sensible than `datetime`, but I'm not sure if the above is still ambiguous - certainly if it was converted to `datetime`, it may result in 10th July or 7th October, depending on language settings. I'd be more comfortable with `'19810710'` which will always be interpreted as 10th July.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this information shortly after asking the question... Too bad

Comment: About that `date` default value, it's just an example... But thanks for the hint!